# Populating Select List Using JQuery Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I have the following code to populate a drop-down box on a form. The code seems to work but it throws an error "**cannot read property id of undefined**".

**jquery**

```
function LoadAnnualCredits() {
    try {
        var $dropdown = $("#creditQty");
        $dropdown.empty();
        var arrayList = [
            { "Id": 5000, "Name": "5,000" },
            { "Id": 10000, "Name": "10,000" }
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i <= arrayList.length; i++) {
            $dropdown.append($("<option />").val(arrayList[i].Id).text(arrayList[i].Name));
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

**Razor View Code**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NumCredits, Model.CreditQty, "Choose Qty", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "creditQty", @style = "width: 160px; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; padding: 4px;", @onchange = "CreditQtyChanged(this.value);" })
```

I tried using forEach method. No error msg but for some strange reason, it gives me duplicate items in the drop-down list:

5,000

5,000

10,000

10,000

```
function LoadAnnualCredits() {
    try {
        var $dropdown = $("#creditQty");
        $dropdown.empty();
        let arrayList = [
            { "Id": 5000, "Name": "5,000" },
            { "Id": 10000, "Name": "10,000" }
        ];
        arrayList.forEach(function (e) {
            $dropdown.append($('<option><option/>').val(e.Id).text(e.Name));
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error can be a condition of the FOR loop, where it is **(i <= arrayList.length)**, change to that **(i < arrayList.length)**, the variable **"i"** **equals 0**, so it does not find a **position equal to 2**, since its array has only two elements (goes to position 1). *Arrays in Javascript start at 0,* so your element of position 2 is not found, that's what you're doing. Just change the condition and this will solve the problem.

Comment: silly me. spent too long working on office interop project where indexing crazily starts at 1. i should have spotted that one. thanks Mateus :)